# EKS cluster doesn't provide client-ca-file

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Created a cluster in EKS (Kubernetes 1.11.5) with multiple node groups however I'm noticing that in the `extension-apiserver-authentication` configmap that `client-ca-file` key is missing.

I assume this is due to the way Kubernetes API service is initiated. Has anyone else come across this issue ?

I came across this problem while deploying certificate manager which queries the api server with `GET https://10.100.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication`.

In GKE this isnt a problem as `extension-apiserver-authentication` configmap already includes `client-ca-file`.

`extension-apiserver-authentication` configmap in AWS,

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  requestheader-allowed-names: '["front-proxy-client"]'
  requestheader-client-ca-file: |
    <certificate file>
  requestheader-extra-headers-prefix: '["X-Remote-Extra-"]'
  requestheader-group-headers: '["X-Remote-Group"]'
  requestheader-username-headers: '["X-Remote-User"]'
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2019-01-14T04:56:51Z
  name: extension-apiserver-authentication
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "39"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication
  uid: ce2b6f64-17b8-11e9-a6dd-021a269d3ce8
```

However in GKE,

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  client-ca-file: |
    <client certificate file>
  requestheader-allowed-names: '["aggregator"]'
  requestheader-client-ca-file: |
    <certificate file>
  requestheader-extra-headers-prefix: '["X-Remote-Extra-"]'
  requestheader-group-headers: '["X-Remote-Group"]'
  requestheader-username-headers: '["X-Remote-User"]'
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-05-24T12:06:33Z
  name: extension-apiserver-authentication
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "32"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication
  uid: e6c0c431-5f4a-11e8-8d8c-42010a9a0191
```

Answer (score 7):

I've also run into this issue while trying to use cert-manager on an AWS EKS cluster. It is possible to inject the certificate yourself using the certificate obtained from the AWS CLI. Follow these steps to address this issue:

**Obtain the Certificate**

The certificate is stored Base64 encoded and can be retrieved using

```sh
aws eks describe-cluster \
        --region=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} \
        --name=${CLUSTER_NAME} \
        --output=text \
        --query 'cluster.{certificateAuthorityData: certificateAuthority.data}' | base64 -D
```

**Inject the Certificate**

Edit configMap/extension-apiserver-authentication under the kube-system namespace: `kubectl -n kube-system edit cm extension-apiserver-authentication`

Under the data section, add the CA under a new config entry named client-ca-file. For example:

```
  client-ca-file: |
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks like something we should fix. Anyone care to create an issue on https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues for it?

Comment: `base64: invalid option -- 'D'`

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions might be correct, I mean your issue might really have to do with the way how api-server is initiated in EKS, and when lacking the [--client-ca-file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/#options) option, according the apiserver source code:

> Cluster doesn't provide client-ca-file in configmap/%s in %s, so
>   client certificate authentication to extension api-server won't work.

I`m wondering if you could create a client-ca by yourself, and update afterwards extension-apiserver-authentication ConfigMap. After all in EKS we have access to CA (the way to get it [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/7f6c8cb3597e17f6e5f7df96d12bccf5604dc909/files/bootstrap.sh#L86)), which can serve us to sign the client certificates, like described in GitHub page with [sample](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-apiserver/blob/master/README.md#running-it-stand-alone) api-server.

As a side comment:

I noticed, that on EKS, components like kubelet , are using `aws-iam-authenticator` (content of `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig` on cluster node):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - eks-api-eval
      command: /usr/bin/aws-iam-authenticator
      env: null
```

in opposite to GKE, where client-ca is used as a way for authenticating clients:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/srv/kubernetes/pki/kubelet.crt
    client-key: /etc/srv/kubernetes/pki/kubelet.key
```

Comment: yeah completely agree. ive reached out to AWS support about this. doesnt look like this flag is required though unlike the request header flags. so may be the managed K8 providers dont need to implement it. nevertheless atleast some doc around this should be produced by them to say so. will post back when i hear back from support.